# Which code is more readable?

Tags: c++, readability, builder-pattern

This isn't a difficult question. I simply want to know which of these two C++ code snippets you think is better (readability vs. length vs. *boiler-platery*):

**Option #1**

```
Entity* square = Entity::Builder().positionX(0.0).positionY(0.0).
    controller(ctrl).representation(rep).build();
```

**Option #2**

```
Entity::Builder bld;
bld.positionX(0.0).positionY(0.0).controller(ctrl).representation(rep);
Entity* square = bld.build();
```

I personally prefer the first option, but that may be because I am the author of the code and already know what the code does (it may be confusing for someone who doesn't know the code). I like it better because it shows the focus on the `Entity` object rather than on the `Entity::Builder` object (and because it's shorter).

Comment: Why not `Entity* square = new Square(0.0, 0.0, ctrl, rep);`?

Comment: It's not a *difficult* question, but it doesn't have a "right" answer, either, which goes against StackOverflow's guidelines.

Comment: @James: This is method chaining.  It's less restrictive than e.g. a constructor call, where you might not want to provide all the arguments.

Comment: I don't know about readability - they both look the same to me - but the second one is creating a superfluous "bld" which may or may not be an issue.

Comment: @Oli: I know, was just curious as to why you would need it for something with (seemingly) so few parameters.  Maybe there is more to the `Square` than meets the eye here.  Objection withdrawn.

Comment: @James I expect the Entity class to grow quite big, so I'll require some sort of mechanism to better handle the large amount of parameters I would have to pass in the constructor. I chose the builder pattern. There's few parameters now, but their number will grow.

Comment: @Paul: Makes sense.  For what it is worth, option 1 seems fine so long as you don't need the builder after you call `build`.

Answer (score 5):

**Option #3**

```
Entity* square = Entity::Builder()
                     .positionX(0.0)
                     .positionY(0.0)
                     .controller(ctrl)
                     .representation(rep)
                     .build();
```

Comment: That's also an option, but I have an irrational dislike for that kind of alignment. :P I use it sometimes, but most of the time it makes me think of old C code. :))

Comment: In such case, it is best to provide a proper constructor method. It improves readability and is less error-prone.

Comment: `boost::python` uses this design extensively, and it works quite neatly.